# Flutter: How to load items lazily when having two nested listview.builders?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, lazy-loading, flutter-listview

In my code I use nested `listview.builder` with `shrinkWrap: true` and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.
The problem is that the items are not loaded lazily because they are nested in a `SingleChildScrollView()`.

However I need a way to have two (or more) `listview.builder` among themselves with only the full screen to be scrollable.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            buildListView(list1),
            buildListView(list2),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget buildListView(List list) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: list[index].toString()),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CustomScrollView`s they are more flexible and powerful than `SingleChildScrollView`s. Also use `Sliver`s instead `ListView`s.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(title: list1[index]);
        },
        childCount: list1.length,
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(title: list2[index]);
        },
        childCount: list2.length,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

You can also create the same build method for Slivers:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext) {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      buildListView(list1),
      buildListView(list2),
    ],
  );
}

Widget buildListView(List list) {
  return SliverList(...);
}
```

All items will be lazy loaded and everything will be available in a single full-screen scrollable area.

See also [`SliverGrid`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverGrid-class.html).